# Change Parameter value using dataset query in SSRS report after execution

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

How do you change the parameter value after execution? I have not found any helpful documentation on this. I have written a stored proc to insert data into a table I created after the user kicks off action where it takes them to another report. In the same stored proc, I have inserted a SET @param = 0 and it is not doing anything.

The stored procedure would look like this for example:

```
BEGIN

    Insert into table
    select 1 as Field1
    ,'abc' as Field2
    WHERE @param = 1;

    SET @param = 0

    SELECT * FROM table

END
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the example code you posted.   What makes you think it is not doing anything?

Comment: Are you trying to return `@param` from the stored procedure? What's your expected result?

Comment: I am trying to change the param in the report from 1 to 0. It is remaining 1 however.